# Mapstruct mapping nested classes

Tags: java, mapping, mapstruct

I have nested classes like that;

```
class Tracing{
   ....some fields
   Set<Step> stepSet;
}
class Step{
   ....some fields
   Set<Action> stepSet;
}
class Action{
   .... some field
}
```

I want to map this classes using Mapstruct, to my hibernate entity classes. They look like that;

```
class TracingDto{
   ....some fields
   Set<Step> stepSet; // relation
}
class StepDto{
   ....some fields
   TracingDto tracing; // relation
   Set<Action> stepSet; // relation
}
class ActionDto{
   ....some fields
   StepDto step; // relation
}
```

I have a mapper interface which includes this three method;

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
interface Mapper{
   TracingDto traceModelToEntity(Tracing tracing);
   StepDto stepModelToEntity(Step step);
   ActionDto actionModelToEntity(Action tracing);
}
```

But, these mapping methods do not create and map base nested classes in entity classes ( => `StepDto` field in `ActionDto` and => `TracingDto` field in `StepDto`). How can i do that.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. The mapper you are showing should  perform the mapping you are expecting. The generated class should have a method that maps `Set<Step>` to `Set<StepDto>` in which your `stepModelToEntity` method would be invoked for each `Step`. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: I try to map Tracing object to TracingDto object. TracingDto includes set<StepDto> field. I want to map TracingDto field which placed in StepDto class with (container object instance) TracingDto. When i call traceModelToEntity function, mapping works successfully for all fields(returns mapped TraceDto). But, TraceDto field of StepDto(nested class) is null. Step class(source class for StepDto mapping) is not include Trace type field so generated source does not include setter for it. I want to map base(container class) to a field of nested (child class)  How can i map?

Comment: Your mapping is correct but i think you the definition of your DTO classes is wrong.  In the TracingDto class, you need a Set<StepDto> not a Set<Step>. In the StepDto  class, your need to have a Set<ActionDto> not a Set<Action>. Another thing, in your StepDto class, you have a TracingDto field but you Step class does not seem to have a Tracing field